# celery configuration update- without redeploying celery

Tags: python, configuration, celery

I'm running flask app, using celery for task queue management.

When running a task, configuration (for instance db credentials) is read from another imported module.

I can't figure out how can i reload the imported configuration module (the imported file reads an external config file when first called), without restarting the celery.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Store any configuration that needs to be reloaded in an .ini file, not in a python module. You can read this using the [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) module.

You file can look like

```
[db]
username = foo
password = bar
host = baz
```

Then you can reload the configuration at any time by doing

```
import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')

db_username = config.get('db', 'username')
db_password = config.get('db', 'password')
db_host = config.get('db', 'host')
```